# Plain text view is not showing in app on android emulator but it shows in Android Studio design tab

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I am Beginner to android i am just following a tutorial.The problem is plain text view is not showing in app on android emulator but it shows in android studio design tab.And i am not understanding why it is not showing. is there any problem with relative view.
can someone please help me. Thanks in advance . 
**my mainActivity code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            try {
                val textValue : String = editTextTextPersonName?.text.toString()
                Toast.makeText(this, textValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } catch (e : Exception){
                Log.i("myactivity", "$e")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**and my xml file code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="491dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="126dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="273dp"
        android:text="@string/pavan" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/punna" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

image
[image: image with design tab and app view]

Comment: Try check your emulator with tools -> layout inspector. There you can see is it actually added to the screen and check it's properties

Comment: yes it not showing in layout inspector and i just replaced realative layout with constraint layout but it showing relative layout

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try and use Constraint Layout instead of RelativeLayout. Relative Layout can be tricky sometimes specially if you're new.

In Constraint Layout you create a view, then attach its constraints to the edges of some views, and that's it. No need for all that XML code like `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX`

Here, check this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtYBBInIIE8

Comment: thank you for your responce. i just tried  constraint layout but it is not working

Comment: when i used button to move into another activity the text view showing with same code written in mainactivity.xml

Comment: can you modify or create another question with the data updated please?

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to use relative layout and **dp** sizes. **dp** sizes depend to phone's size so it will differ in different phones. Here as you see in design tab you haven't notification bar meanwhile in emulator you have it. I recommend you to use TextView instead of EditText.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into the same issue. The solution is to find out if your device is running on API level 21 or higher, if it is then look for v21 activity_main.xml and type your code there. It is located in app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml(v21)